# How can I forcefully add .mp4 or .webm extension when uploading video?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

How could I possibly add an extension of .mp4 or .webm? It only produces like this

[image: video without extension]

HTML

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="inpVid" accept="video/*">
<video style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px;" controls id="vidURL">
  <source id="videoUrl" src="#" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
    function changeVideoURL (element) {
      const videoURLElement = document.getElementById('videoUrl')
      const videoPlayer = document.getElementById('vidURL')
      if (element.files && element.files[0]) {
        videoURLElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(element.files[0]);
        videoPlayer.load()
      }      
    }
    document.getElementById("inpVid").onchange = function() {
      changeVideoURL(this)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is `accept=".webm,.mp4"` what you want?

Comment: I put this. Not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you seek

`<input type="file[]" id="inpVid" accept="video/mp4,video/webm" />`

Comment: It still doesn't add `.mp4` at the end of the blob:link :( [image result](https://imgur.com/a/Sq0VX38)

Comment: I think that updating the result after uploading to the blob is on Backend not from Frontend. The Frontend usage of `accept=""` attribute will only disallow the upload of any different videos than specified in the attribute value.

Comment: The <script> is the one who uploads the video.

Comment: I was mistaken, blob is not managed by the backend as I mentioned in the last comment. But however it is created internally by the browser and can be used in only once in the same instance of the browser and in the same session. So it doesn't represent the real URL of the video